# How to collect Usage Statistics in Spring Security

Tags: java, session, spring-mvc, spring-security, usage-statistics

In my Spring mvc3 Java EE web application, I am using spring security for user session management.

Now I want to collect usage statistics of an authenticated user (statistics like usage of urls and all). My aim is to collect all those data from the controllers and all in an user session and persist them into db after the user logged out or the session expires, without compromising the application performance.

Is implementing HttpSessionListener is a good way to do it, or there is some better, standardized and elegant way?